# How can I print a .txt to my .py?

Tags: python

How can I fix it, I'm trying to call a .txt file(dictionary) to my .py and I am trying to split the dictionary and call it with out the `|`.

For example:

```
Please | help me 
Please : help me
```

My code:

```
def load_library(file):
    with open(file,'rt') as x:
        mylist = x.split("|")
        for y in mylist:
            mod = getattr(x, y)
        return mod
```

Comment: I wish there's no problem with my edit...however, what do you want to do?

Comment: how does your input file look like? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks you made it better, I have a dictionary txt file and I want to call it or print it by making a function but I want to replace | in my dictionary to be : in my printed output

Comment: My input file is same as my example with more lines and every line has "|" this once same as my example and I want it to be printed without it

Comment: your example is not a dictionary.

Comment: It's a .txt file and I saved something in it similar to my example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I can understand, this is what you are trying to do.

```
def load_lib(file):
     allTheData = []
     with open(file,"r") as f:
          for line in f:
              data = line.split("|")
              ####DO something
              # data[1] is the stuff after |
              printAsYouWant(data)
              ## allTheData holds all the definitions
              allTheData.append(data[0] + ":" + data[1])
          printList(allTheData)

def printAsYouWant(data):
   print(data[0] + ":" + data[1])
####PRINT THE DATA
def printList(yourData):
    for i in yourData:
         print(i)
```

> You can modify `printAsYouWant(data)` to change your data out.

Or, as one function.

```
def load_lib(file):
     allTheData = []
     with open(file,"r") as f:
          for line in f:
              data = line.split("|")
              ####DO something
              # data[1] is the stuff after |
              print(data[0] + ":" + data[1])
              allTheData.append(data[0] + ":" + data[1])
          for i in allTheData:
              print(i)
```

EDIT: From what I can see, this should work as you specify in your question.

Comment: no need for `f.close()` when you are using the `with` statement.

Comment: What do you mean "make it in a list"?

Comment: I added to my answer to make it a list.

Comment: Thanks that's great but i was asked to make one function only and the automatic checker will print the output I just need to put return at the end of one function?

Comment: Hang on one second.  The use of multiple function is just abstraction.

Comment: @Misha Take a look now

Comment: Exactly thanks that's what I wanted but if I want to make another one function and to invert data 0 with data data 1 from the same dictionary for example "help me : please" from the above example.... I can maybe call it from my first function and invert it or make a new function that calls it directly from the dictionary and invert it?

Comment: First, duplicate the function.  Next, in the print statement, change the zero and one.  Do the Same for the append.  That should do it